# Display formatted price only if Woocommerce product price is higher than zero otherwise display a text

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements, price

Hello I am new to wordpress and woocommerce, I want to enter a conditional that when the price of a product is zero "0", it shows a text "Price to Consult", and when the price is greater than zero "price> 0", it shows the price.

I am entering the price.php file and when modifying the following code, it throws an error on the web page.

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $product;
?>

<p class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>
```

---

Edit:

Now I have the following code (I don't know if it is correct.):

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $product;
$precio->get_price_html()  
?>

<p class="price"><?php echo 
if($product->get_price_html()>0) {
            $product->get_price_html()
} else{
echo "price to consult"
}; ?></p>
```

Which gives me this error: critical error on your website.

Comment: [The manual on `if()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php) is a good start.

Comment: *"it throws an error on the web page."* - What is the error you are getting? And from what code?

Comment: enter the following code, I don't know. 

if it is correct. if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
 exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

global $product;
$precio->get_price_html()  
?>

<p class="price"><?php echo 
if($product->get_price_html()>0) {
            $product->get_price_html()
} else{
echo "price to consult"
}; ?></p>

Comment: I have, and nothing in there suggests an `if()`. See the link I posted.